# Custom Spinner error in android

Tags: android

I have 2 spinners. i am loading the spinner data from database.When i select any item in first spinner, depending on that item, the second spinner should load corresponding data.For example, if choose vegetables in first spinner then only vegetables name should come in second and if choose fruits in 1st, then fruits name should come in second.How can i pass the selected item in 1st spinner to my Customized spinner class?
I tried to pass that item, but its giving me blank in every row of second spinner.
here is my code

```
   // Spinner click listener
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView,
                        View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    label = paramAdapterView.getItemAtPosition(paramInt)
                            .toString();
                    deviceID = paramInt;
                    loadSpinnerData1(label);

                }
       private void loadSpinnerData1(String type) {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                 //getting the spinner item depending on what item selected in 1st spinner
                List<String> manuft = db.getAllManuft(type);
        spinner1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(OptionsActivity.this, R.layout.row, manuft,type));
    }
```

My custom spinner class

```
        public class MyAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> manuft, String type) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, manuft);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent, label);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent, label);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, String type) {

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            List<String> manuft = db.getAllManuft(type);

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.device);

            for(int i=0;i<manuft.size();i++){
                label.setText(manuft.get(position));
            }


            return row;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats there in `db.getAllManuft(type);`? I mean what it is returning exactly. Have you tried look at the response of that function.

Comment: yes it is returning correctly. And created row for every item but that item name is not showing.

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 Post full error logcat.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya i think she is not getting any issue :)

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 i found lacking of best practices in your code. 1) Follow view holder pattern 2) if you are passing data to your custom adapter then why are you again fetching the same data in your getCustomView() method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I will Try to learn good practices for coding.

Comment: @PareshMayani  i got my answer.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya thanks.. got answer

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 you should share solution here by posting answer.

Comment: Actually That string(passed to Textview is balnk)so i made that to String type;this.type = typename; globaly.So that it refect to that textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//declare the item selected globaly

```
  String type;
```

Then make this.type=typename; in loadspinner

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
                    // this method will update your second spinner
            updateSecondSpinner(id);


        }
```

Here the method to update the second spinner:

```
    private void updateSecondSpinner(long id) {

                String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) };
                cur2 = db.rawQuery("select IID AS _id, TXNAME from TABLE WHERE IID= ?", args);

                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter_2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AccidentNewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur2,
                    new String[] { "TXNAME" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinner_modelo.setAdapter(adapter2);

...
}
```